# How to get the path of a file in comparison to another file (VSCode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am in file A and need to import file B. There is a complex file structure. I don't want to use the absolute path. How can I copy the path to file B from file A?

Comment: Unclear. Can you give an example?

Comment: To you mean the relative path from File A to file B?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do it in VS Code but this extension does it very well: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32311148)